# edit object in observableCollection by selecting in listbox and opening new window to edit it . wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, observablecollection

I have an observable collection "vehicles" containing vehicles, of class "car" "bike" or "van", each is inherited from a "vehicle Class,

```
public ObservableCollection<Vehicle> vehicles = new ObservableCollection<Vehicle>();

Car car3 = new Car("Volkswagon", "Golf", "8000", "Red", "2000", "300000", "not so bad", "1.5litre", Car.BodyType.Hatchback);
            Car car4 = new Car("Audi", "A6", "19000", "Red", "20014", "20000", "hannnnndy", "2litre", Car.BodyType.Saloon);

            vehicles.Add(car1);
            vehicles.Add(car2);
            vehicles.Add(car3);
            vehicles.Add(car4);

            Van van1 = new Van("Ford", "transit", "25000", "white", "2008", "100000", "lovely red car", "1.4litre", Van.WheelBase.Medium, Van.VanType.Unlisted);
            Van van2 = new Van("Citroen", "berlingo", "2000", "silver", "2006", "20100", "lovely", "1.4litre", Van.WheelBase.Long, Van.VanType.PanelVan);
```

These vehicles are being displayed in a listbox "lbxVehicles"

```
lbxVehicles.ItemsSource = vehicles;
```

I need to be able to select one of the vehicles being displayed in the listbox and when I click an edit button, open a new window and edit the details and when I click a button on the new window the selected object in the observable collection will be edited. what i was trying to do was. **First window:**

```
    private void Button_ClickEdit(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                Vehicle selVehicle = lbxVehicles.SelectedItem as Vehicle;
                if (selVehicle != null)
                {
                    WindowEdit winE = new WindowEdit();
                    winE.Owner = this;
                    winE.edit = selVehicle;
                    winE.ShowDialog();
                }
            }
```

then on window 2:

```
public partial class WindowEdit : Window
    {
        public object edit = new object();
        public WindowEdit()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

This is just what I tried but I'm pretty sure it is wrong. Any help is much appreciated, and since I am trying to learn as much as I can if you can explain any possible solutions that would be great

Comment: One issue I noticed is that you assigning this: `winE.edit = selVehicle;` **AFTER** you call `winE.ShowDialog();`. `ShowDialog` is blocking the execution of the method. (=Modal Window). That means, when you close the `winE` dialog, the `winE.edit` is assigned. You probably want to assign it before you open the window. Else your `winE.edit` will be NULL when the window is showing

Comment: Thank you for that, I have it changed now so I'll update the code here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. 
The thing you need to set is your second window's DataContext to be the instance of the vehicle. This way, you can edit all the properties using the Vehicle class's properties.

Make a note that class Vehicle needs to inherit **INotifyPropertyChanged** for this to work, and you need to use the **NotifyPropertyChanged** everytime you SET a value on the Vehicle property.

Some guidance on the MVVM pattern here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/100175/Model-View-ViewModel-MVVM-Explained

Comment: I have to read up a little but I think it has me on the right path. I will mark as accepted answer If I get it working, Thank you for your help!

Comment: No problem. The trick with MVVM is understanding how each class "notifies" the UI that it has changed. Once you get that "eureka-moment", the rest is smooth sailing, but it will take you a few attempts (at least it did for me, hehe)